# Swift 3: nested UIView(s) corners not getting rounded

Tags: ios, uiview, swift3, cornerradius

I have a **UIView** named **parent**. Inside parent are nested two UIViews named **Child1** and **Child2**.(see image)
[image: Parent-Child Relation]

Note: There are **no margins** i.e. 0 margin b/w both Child1, Child2 and Parent.

I am trying to **round the corners of Parent**.

```
parentView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
```

This **does not round** up the corners of the children.(see image)

[image: The top corners do not get rounded]

The **top corners** do **not** end up getting **round** here. The bottom corners are rounded because Child2 is transparent while Child1 is colored. Parent is white in color.

What I've tried so far:

```
parentView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
child1.clipsToBounds = true
```

No luck

```
parentView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
maskLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: view.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft, .topRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)).cgPath
child1.layer.mask = maskLayer
```

Still No luck

Please help me out

Comment: set .clipsToBounds = true. That will hide the overflow of the layer

Comment: child and parent both cornerRadius and  clipsToBounds = true

Comment: Set `masksToBounds` of parent layer to true.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I think you need to add `clipToBound` on `parentView`

```
parentView.clipsToBounds = true
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!!

Comment: This also can be set in the Interface Builder - Attributes Inspector - Drawing

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 2):

If you need cornerRadius

```
import QuartzCore

parentView.layer.cornerRadius = yourvalue
```

if you don't want to shadow then add

```
parentView.layer.masksToBounds = true
```